# Not generating PDF/ image file from HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html, image

I am using [mPDF](https://mpdf.github.io/) and other library for generating PDF/ Image from HTML code or file. below I have mentioned my HTML code from which need to generate .JPG or .PNG or .PDF

```
<HTML>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://codeclippers.xyz/320x50/app.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="addsp320x50"></div>
</body>
<script src="http://codeclippers.xyz/320x50/app.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var availbleTitles = ["title1", "title2", "title3", "title"];
var availableVsprite =["https:\/\/dspbanners.s3.amazonaws.com\/creatives\/user_creatives_5f843d6b40d48_1602501995.jpeg", "https:\/\/dspbanners.s3.amazonaws.com\/creatives\/user_creatives_5f843d6b7e2b0_1602501995.jpeg"];
var availableVicons = [""];
var availbleBasicOptions = [""];
var availbleDescription = [""];
var selectedVsprite = availableVsprite[Math.floor(Math.random() * availableVsprite.length)];
var selectedVicons = availableVicons[Math.floor(Math.random() * availableVicons.length)];
var selectedTitles = availbleTitles[Math.floor(Math.random() * availbleTitles.length)];
var selectedDescription = availbleDescription[Math.floor(Math.random() * availbleDescription.length)];
var selectedBasicOpt = availbleBasicOptions[Math.floor(Math.random() * availbleBasicOptions.length)];
cOptions.isAnimated = true;
cOptions.animatedVariation = "vinfinite-scroll";
cOptions.titleText = selectedTitles;
cOptions.animationOptions[0].verticalInfiniteAnimation[0].backgroundSpriteURL = selectedVsprite;
if(selectedVicons != "") {
cOptions.animationOptions[0].verticalInfiniteAnimation[0].showIcon = true;
cOptions.animationOptions[0].verticalInfiniteAnimation[0].actionIconImage = selectedVicons;
}
cOptions.descrptionText = selectedDescription;
for(const [key, value] of Object.entries(selectedBasicOpt)) {
if(typeof value === 'boolean') {
cOptions[key] = value;
} else {
cOptions[key] = value.replace(/"/g, "").trim()
}
}
renderCreative();
</script>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: *Which* other library? Where's your php code?

Comment: @Gabriel I have used phantommagick library too.